# Running a macro on a protected sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run a macro in VBA which lists all the files of a specific folder as well as their hyperlinks. My code works when it is unprotected. But it does not work when it is protected. This is my hyperlink macro. All my other macros work when the sheets are protected. Just not the hyperlink one. I have stored the private sub macro in **ThisWorkbook**

```
Sub updatting()

Dim xFSO As Object
    Dim xFolder As Object
    Dim xFile As Object
    Dim xPath As String
    Dim I As Integer
    xPath = "C:\Users\risha\Downloads\a_few_little_tests\New folder"
    If xPath = "" Then Exit Sub
    Set xFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set xFolder = xFSO.GetFolder(xPath)
    For Each xFile In xFolder.Files
        I = I + 1
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Cells(I, 14), xFile.Path, , , xFile.Name
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()


Sheet3.Protect Password:="abc", UserInterFaceOnly:=True



End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure that the active sheet is `Sheet3`?

Comment: Yes, when I unprotect it, it works. It's not working under protection. I can use sheet. unprotect, but that would be risky in case there is an error in the code then the sheet would remain unprotected.

Comment: It should be working. I tested now on Excel 2016. If you are afraid of remaining it unprotected, implement error handling and make the code jumping there, where to protect the sheet in case of an error.

Comment: Ok, I will try error handling. I'm not getting any errors when I run the code I posted above. But the hyperlinks are mixed up, each one being the wrong file. And some filenames do not show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this after I = I + 1

```
   I = I + 1
  ActiveSheet.Cells(I, 14).Value = xFile.Name
  ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Cells(I, 14), xFile.Path, , , xFile.Name
```